# How to use foreach in PySpark to write to a kafka topic?

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to insert a refined log created on each row through `foreach` & want to store into a Kafka topic as follows -

```
def refine(df):
    log = df.value
    event_logs = json.dumps(get_event_logs(log)) #A function to refine the row/log
    pdf = pd.DataFrame({"value": event_logs}, index=[0])

    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("myAPP").getOrCreate() 
    df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)

    query = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") \
       .write \
       .format("kafka") \
       .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
       .option("topic", "intest") \
       .save()
```

And I am calling it using the following code.

```
query = streaming_df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")  \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("console") \
    .foreach(refine)\
    .start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

But the `refine` function is somehow unable to get Kafka packages I sent while submitting the code. I believe the executioner has no access to the Kafka package send via the following command -

```
./bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.1 ...
```

because when I submit my code, I get the following error message,

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide".;
```

So, my question is how to sink data into Kafka inside `foreach`? And as a side question I want to know if it's a good idea to create another session inside `foreach`; I had to redeclare session inside `foreach` because the exiting session of the main driver couldn't be used inside foreach for some issues regarding serializability.

P.S: If I try to sink it to console (`...format("console")`) inside `foreach`, then it works without any error.